# On a modular arithmetic problem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m_1$ and $m_2$ be coprime with $\phi(p)\nmid(m_1-m_2)$

Let $m_1m_4\equiv m_2m_3\bmod\phi(p)$ where $p=2q+1$ and $q$ is prime and $p$ is prime and $\phi(p)$ is totient of $p$.

Is it true $\phi(p)$ and $(m_2-m_4)$ are not coprime?

Likewise is it true $\phi(p)$ and $(m_3-m_1)$ are not coprime?

Comment: @lulu Sorry coprimality is what I was after.

Comment: Well...have you considered trying any examples?   Take $q=3$, so $p=7$ and $\varphi(p)=6$.  Then note that $1\times 6=1\times 6$.  And yet $6$ is relatively prime to $-5$.  So...what are you asking?

Comment: $m_1=m_2=1$ implies $6|(m_1-m_2)$

Comment: Again, please consider trying examples.  Use $6\times 2=3\times 4$ if you prefer.

Comment: $m_1=6$ and $m_2=3$ are not coprime.

Comment: Fair enough.  So $6\times 2 = 1\times 12$

Comment: $m_1=6$ and $m_3=12$ makes $(m_3-m_1)$ divisible by $\phi(p)$.

Comment: But $m_2-m_4=-1$ is prime to $6$, and that's what you asked.

Comment: Correct but both cannot be coprime?

Comment: I have no idea.  I just know that this is a counterexample to your first question.  Perhaps you can modify your question in such a way so that this is not a counterexample to the new question but one should be cautious about these constantly-evolving questions (where the question changes every time a counterexample is produced).  If you have a clear question, backed up by lots of examples, then ask that.